# ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar la fecha actual-1 pero establecer el rango de horas en que se ejecuta la consulta? Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-12c

necesito programar una consulta para que se ejecute diariamente y me muestre la información del día anterior completo, pero debido a que debe quedar programada no puedo establecer la fecha diariamente por lo que he intentado usar `sysdate-1` y la franja horaria, sin embargo, sin importar si uso TO_DATE o TO_CHAR me genera el siguiente error al ejecutar la consulta:

> ORA-01830: la máscara de formato de fecha termina antes de convertir toda la cadena de entrada
> 01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"

¿Es posible programar esta consulta de algún modo?

El código es el siguiente:

```
    SELECT
HORA HORA_MAX,
FECHA,
VENDOR,
SECTOR,
NUM_TU_DL,
DEN_TU_DL,
TU_DL_MBPS,
NUM_TU_UL,
DEN_TU_UL,  
TU_UL_MBPS,
USERS_RR_AVG,
USERS_RR_PEAK          
FROM
(
SELECT Y.*,
------- Por día, en caso de repetidos de cantidad de usuarios escoge el de la fecha màs alta 
HORA||'-'||MAX(FECHA) OVER (PARTITION BY HORA,SECTOR) MAX_KPI_FECHA,
HORA||'-'||FECHA KPI_FECHA

FROM
(
SELECT Z.*, 
--------Por día, escoge el valor mas alto de usuarios de las 7 muestras BBH diarias 
HORA||'-'||MAX(USERS_RR_AVG) OVER (PARTITION BY HORA,SECTOR) MAX_KPI_USERS,
HORA||'-'||USERS_RR_AVG KPI_USERS
FROM
(-----RAW BBH DIARIA
SELECT
'E' VENDOR,
PORTADORA,
B.SECTOR,
B.DATETIME_ID FECHA,
CASE WHEN  TO_CHAR(B.DATETIME_ID+1,'HH24') =  '01' 
     THEN max(TO_CHAR(B.DATETIME_ID,'')) over (partition by  TO_CHAR(B.DATETIME_ID+1,'HH24'))
     ELSE min(TO_CHAR(B.DATETIME_ID,'')) over (partition by  TO_CHAR(B.DATETIME_ID+1,'HH24'))
     END||''||TO_CHAR(B.DATETIME_ID+1,'HH24') HORA,
CASE WHEN PRB_DL_AVAIL > 0 AND PRB_DL_AVAIL <= 25 THEN 25
     WHEN PRB_DL_AVAIL > 25 AND PRB_DL_AVAIL <= 50 THEN 50
     WHEN PRB_DL_AVAIL > 50 THEN 75 ELSE PRB_DL_AVAIL END PRB_DL_AVAIL,
B.NUM_TU_DL,
B.DEN_TU_DLU,
B.TU_DL_MBPS,
B.NUM_TU_UL,
B.DEN_TU_UL,    
B.TU_UL_MBPS,
B.USERS_RR_AVG,
B.USERS_RR_PEAK 
FROM
lt_e_bbh_day B
WHERE   DATETIME_ID  >=     TO_DATE (SYSDATE-1,'MM/DD/YYYY') ||' 00:00:00' AND
DATETIME_ID   <=    TO_DATE (SYSDATE-1,'MM/DD/YYYY') ||' 23:59:59' 

UNION ALL

SELECT
'H' VENDOR,
PORTADORA,
W.SECTOR,
W.STARTTIME FECHA,
CASE WHEN  TO_CHAR(W.STARTTIME+1,'HH24') =  '01' 
     THEN max(TO_CHAR(W.STARTTIME,'')) over (partition by  TO_CHAR(W.STARTTIME+1,'HH24'))
     ELSE min(TO_CHAR(W.STARTTIME,'')) over (partition by  TO_CHAR(W.STARTTIME+1,'HH24'))
     END||''||TO_CHAR(W.STARTTIME+1,'HH24') HORA,

CASE WHEN PRB_DL_AVAIL > 0 AND PRB_DL_AVAIL <= 25 THEN 25
     WHEN PRB_DL_AVAIL > 25 AND PRB_DL_AVAIL <= 50 THEN 50
     WHEN PRB_DL_AVAIL > 50 THEN 75 ELSE PRB_DL_AVAIL END PRB_DL_AVAIL,
W.NUM_TU_DL,
W.DEN_TU_DL,
W.TU_DL_MBPS,
W.NUM_TU_UL,
W.DEN_TU_UL,    
W.TU_UL_MBPS,
W.USERS_RR_AVG,
W.USERS_RR_PEAK
FROM
lt_h_bbh_day W
WHERE
STARTTIME  >=    TO_DATE (SYSDATE-1,'MM/DD/YYYY') ||' 00:00:00' AND
STARTTIME   <=     TO_DATE (SYSDATE-1,'MM/DD/YYYY') ||' 23:59:59'
) Z
) Y
WHERE
MAX_KPI_USERS = KPI_USERS
) X
WHERE
MAX_KPI_FECHA = KPI_FECHA
order by 
X.SECTOR desc
```

Si realizara la consulta con una fecha especifica el formato que usaría en ambas tablas es ('04/04/2022 23:59:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')

Comment: sql-server u oracle? las etiquetas filtran y le dan prioridad a quienes revisan las preguntas, facilitando que los que tienen más conocimiento de un tema, lenguaje o herramienta te ayuden más rápido. Usar etiquetas irrelevantes puede demorar la ayuda

Comment: Lo otro: si estás **comparando** dos campos DATETIME, para qué aplicarle máscara a un dato (SYSDATE) que YA está en formato de timestamp? Eso tendría sentido si estuvieras transformando un varchar o algo así